# How Can I update the value of these nested dict object?

Tags: python, json, dictionary, multidimensional-array, facebook-app-requests

I was trying to update the value of **all_friends_paginating_after_cursor** in the dict values, I tried deferent ways but didn't work how can I update the value?

```
a= {"doc_id": "1", "method": "post", "locale": "user", "pretty": "false", "format": "json", "purpose": "fetch", "fb_api_client_context": "{\"load_next_page_counter\":1,\"client_connection_size\":20}", "variables": "{\"profile_id\":\"1\",\"profile_image_size\":180,\"all_friends_paginating_first\":20,\"all_friends_paginating_at_stream_use_customized_batch\":false,\"all_friends_paginating_after_cursor\":\"AQHR4waNWT-YvaXk-AXhRmdl2ldevUdzx_TybGh2ggSielOYRQc-jOZsdsffdsfdsfdsfds1_g\"}", "fb_api_req_friendly_name": "AllFriendListContentQuery", "fb_api_caller_class": "ConnectionManager", "fb_api_analytics_tags": "[\"GraphServices\",\"At_Connection\"]", "client_trace_id": "jj89u654654465", "server_timestamps": "true"}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that `"variables"` (which contains `"all_friends_paginating_after_cursor"`) is a JSON string. One possible way you could do this is convert it into a dict, change the value, then convert it to a string again. Check out this code snippet:

```py
import json
variables = json.loads(a["variables"])
variables["all_friends_paginating_after_cursor"] = "NEW VALUE"
a["variables"] = json.dumps(variables)
```